# FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

```
$googleadsensecode ="a"
"script async src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
<!-- CSGO investing -->
<ins class='adsbygoogle'
 style='display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px';
 data-ad-client='ca-pub-5887577755866658';
 data-ad-slot='8619972228'></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>"
//now outputting this to HTML
echo $googleadsensecode;
```

I cant seem to figure out why im getting an error on line 11
FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line number 11
It has to have something to do with the parenthesis but I don't know how to do it any other way, please help.

Comment: Two double quotes right after each other: `"a""s...`  <- Escape them, otherwise there is nothing between those two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Review

```
$googleadsensecode ="a""script
```

Maybe

```
$googleadsensecode ="script
```